# Maven fixing broken dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven

I just checked out maven based java project from svn to local box in eclipse where maven 3.0.2 is available. However while reviewing class path configuration many of dependencies are broken such as org.restlet-2.0.15.jar. Strange part is C:/Users/daeyoung/.m2/repository has that broken jar file but .lastUpdated is appended. After reading many posts from WWW, the way I understood to fix the problem is delete *.lastUpdated file then re-download it from central repo.

But when I reviewed pom.xml file there is no mention of repository (strange...) and as soon as I delete *.lastUpdated file, it comes back (e.g. org.restlet-2.0.15.jar.lastUpdated).

I am new to Maven.

I'd appreciate if someone can guide me to a right direction to fix this problem.

[image]

[update]

I created following user settings.xml file under /Users/daeyoung/.m2/ directory. I thought at least that would take care of downloading org.restlet package.

[image]

However when I ran mvn command (literally mvn) inside of project folder, system was saying..

[image]

I don't want to modify pom.xml file but rather via user settings.xml I thought I could connect to maven restlet repo and download specified target package but I am not sure what I am missing in here. I think contents of settings.xml is not correct.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://restlet.com/downloads/current/

Comment: the repository is not mentioned because it uses default values, that's the main philosphy behind maven: convention over configuration. did you try to delete the whole directory of the library version on the local cache?

Comment: Don't use such old and buggy Maven versions....

Comment: you probably need to add the org.restlet repository to your settings or maven proxy (as @A.DiMatteo pointed out). The filename "org.restlet" is derived from the artifactId and that one is not found in maven central. So you need to add a source where to get it (prefer repository proxy over settings.xml over pom.xml (dont add that into pom.xml!)

Comment: @A. Di Matteo: I will delete the entire directory ( .m2/repository) to see what happens. Thanks for your advice especially about missing repository info from pom.xml file.

Comment: @A. Di Matteo: I removed entire .m2 directory and re-started IDE but that didn't fix the issue. .m2 directory was re-created. I am not in a position to change pom file (someone else's project) all I am allowed to do is touching java src files (create/delete/update). I wonder if I have to re-install maven with latest version in my local box would do?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to say thanks to all who have given me advice. First I was not well equipped to understand the advice but more I looked at the problem/read about maven articles. It was clear what needs to be done to fix the problem.
Bottom line is I manually downloaded dependencies to ${user_name}/.m2/repository for missing jars. I configured ${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/settings.xml to point to local repository then I ran mvn validate/clean/package sequentially from eclipse via m2e plugin (or I could have done same thing from command line).